# Slow MicroSoft Visual Studio 2022 Performance When Looking at package (.dtsx) files and their content

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to investigate an issue in an SSIS package (.dstx file) using MicroSoft Visual Studio 2022.

Each time I select a component to get an advance editor e.g. for an OLE DB Command it hangs for 10 mins apparently doing nothing but then opening.

Selecting the SQLCommand box to see it's content is equally as slow.

Anyone go any ideas as to why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: I have the issue a lot, it is because I am remoted into another machine to use Visual Studio and the files for the package are stored on network (not the machine I remoted into).  When I saved the files directly to the C drive of the machine it improved dramatically.  I still had some issues with slowness and crashing (that is due to the machine I remoted into more so than Visual Studio), but saving it on the C drive was a huge help.